# Difference between executing a single vs multiple queries at a time in PostgreSQL through Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I am trying to connect to Postgres database and execute some queries which are in an `.sql` file. I did it in 2 ways,

1. Read one query from the `.sql` file at a time and execute it.

   ```
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
   LOGGER.info("Connection established");
   ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(con);
   Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                   new FileReader(sqlPath));
   LOGGER.info("Running the script file");
   sr.runScript(reader);
   ```
2. Read the entire `.sql` file and append it to a string buffer and execute all the statements at the same time.

   ```
   public boolean executeDBScripts(String aSQLScriptFilePath, Statement stmt)     throws IOException,SQLException {
   boolean isScriptExecuted = false;
   try {
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aSQLScriptFilePath));
   String str;
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
   sb.append(str + "\n ");
   }
   in.close();
   stmt.executeUpdate(sb.toString());
   isScriptExecuted = true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
   System.err.println("Failed to Execute" + aSQLScriptFilePath +". The error is"+ e.getMessage());
   } 
   return isScriptExecuted;
   ```

I would like to know the difference between these 2 ways.Is there any other way of doing it because my SQL file has 1000's of sql statements

Comment: How exactly do you do that? Many ways to issue queries won't let you run more than one at a time (without wrapping into database-specific block syntax).

Comment: The second one is not officially supported because JDBC theoretically only allows to run a single statement with one `Connection.execute()` call. @Thilo: the Postgres JDBC driver _does_ allow execution of more than one statement (as long as they are properly separated using `;`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name does that bring with it any transactional semantics? Such as "run them in a single transaction even when I am in the default auto-commit mode"?

Comment: ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(con);
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(sqlPath));LOGGER.info("Running the script file");
   sr.runScript(reader);

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: But some databases know the notion of statement batches (run with JDBC `execute()`, not with `executeUpdate()`), and others have anonymous procedural blocks, where several statements can be batched. And then, there's JDBC batch, of course...

Comment: @LukasEder: yes, but those "batches" are still single statements from the driver's point of view

Comment: I've opened an issue for this topic. https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/390

Answer (score 0):

PgJDBC splits up statements client side and dispatches them separately to the server.

Its SQL parser isn't super bright. In particular, last time I checked it didn't support `$$` quoting. It's just been rewritten in the latest release of the driver, so this might've just improved.

I don't immediately recall how it handles result sets from multi-statement `execute(...)` - whether it discards all but the last result set or if it accumulates them as multiple result sets accessible with `Statement.getMoreResults()` like when `executeBatch()` is used. A quick test program should confirm that.

I also can't immediately remember if it sends a `Sync` between each statement or not, i.e. forces a round-trip. You can check either by examining PgJDBC's debug logs with debug logging enabled, or via Wireshark, which knows how to decode the PostgreSQL protocol.

Ideally, what we'd have would be an extension interface in PgJDBC that could parse a SQL script for you and run it statement by statement, returning a result that was equivalent to running it as a batch. `PGConnection.runScript(...)` or whatever. Nobody's wanted that enough to implement it though.

For now, I'd suggest splitting it up statement-by-statement and running it, at least for big scripts. Or submitting a patch to add a `runScript` feature to PgJDBC of course ... patches are always welcome ;)

Comment: The driver _does_  correctly return multiple ResultSets through `getMoreResults()` if more than one `select` statement was executed.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name . I know this is a bit of a lazy answer.